Norm of linear operator on sum of element
Consider Banach space $B$ and $D$, I was thinking about the following:

Fix any continuous linear operator $T: B \to D$, does there exists a better bound than the operator norm such that for any $b_{1},b_{2} \in B$ that are linearly independent and satisfy $$\|T(b_{1})\|\leq \alpha \|b_{1}\|\quad\mbox{and}\quad \|T(b_{2})\|\leq \beta \|b_{2}\|,$$ we have something like $$\|T(b_{1}+b_{2})\|\leq C_{\alpha,\beta}\|b_{1}+b_{2}\|$$ where $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ is a constant.


I know this might not be completely rigorous, but overall I just want some intuition on whether the condition $$\|T(b_{1})\| \leq \alpha \|b_{1}\|\quad\mbox{and}\quad \|T(b_{2})\|\leq \beta \|b_{2}\|$$ give us any bound on $\|T(b_{1}+b_{2})\|$ that is not the trivial operator norm.
I guess one can also consider stricter case when $B$ and $D$ are finite dimensional Hilbert space for instance.


If $B$ is finite dimensional then $T$ is continuous and bounded, and the claim is true.

@daw  Yes, you can always bound it with the operator norm. I probably meant something else, maybe something like if we assume $C_{\alpha, \beta}$ is strictly less than the operator norm? I just wonder if there is a bound in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$

The answer is negative in the following sense: there is some nonzero matrix $T\in M_2(\mathbb R)$ such that for any $\alpha,\beta>0$, there exist two linearly independent vectors $b_1,b_2\in\mathbb R^2$ that satisfy $\|Tb_1\|_2\le\alpha\|b_1\|_2,\,\|Tb_2\|_2\le\beta\|b_2\|_2$ and $\|T(b_1+b_2)\|_2=\|T\|_2\|b_1+b_2\|_2$. Example:
$$
T=\pmatrix{1\\ &0},
\quad b_1=\pmatrix{0\\ 1}\quad\text{and}
\quad b_2=\pmatrix{\beta\\ -1}.
$$
